# Can I mapDispatchToProps without mapStateToProps in Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am breaking apart Redux' todo example to try to understand it. I read that `mapDispatchToProps` allows you to map dispatch actions as props, so I thought of rewriting `addTodo.js` to use mapDispatchToProps instead of calling dispatch(addTodo()). I called it `addingTodo()`. Something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import addTodo from '../actions';

let AddTodo = ({addingTodo}) => {
  let input;
  return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={e => {
          e.preventDefault()
          if (!input.value.trim()) {
            return
          }
          addingTodo(input.value)
          input.value = ""
        }}>
          <input ref={node => {
            input = node
          }} />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
  )
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  addingTodo: addTodo
}

AddTodo = connect(
  mapDispatchToProps
)(AddTodo)

export default AddTodo
```

However, when I run the app, I get this error: `Error: Invalid value of type object for mapStateToProps argument when connecting component AddTodo.`. I never used `mapStateToProps` to begin with on AddTodo component, so I was not sure what was wrong. My gut feeling says that `connect()` expects `mapStateToProps` to precede `mapDispatchToProps`.

The working original looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import addTodo from '../actions';

let AddTodo = ({dispatch}) => {
  let input;
  return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={e => {
          e.preventDefault()
          if (!input.value.trim()) {
            return
          }
          dispatch(addTodo(input.value))
          input.value = ""
        }}>
          <input ref={node => {
            input = node
          }} />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
  )
}

AddTodo = connect()(AddTodo)

export default AddTodo
```

Complete repo can be found [here](https://github.com/IggHub/understanding-redux).

So my question is, is it possible to do mapDispatchToProps without mapStateToProps? Is what I am trying to do an acceptable practice - if not, why not?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just pass `null` as first argument:

```
AddTodo = connect(
    null,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(AddTodo)
```

Yes, it's not just acceptable practice, it's recommended way to trigger actions. Using `mapDispatchToProps` allows to hide the fact of using redux inside your react components

Comment: But can I use mapStateToProps without mapDispatchToProps the same way?

Comment: @VelizarAndreevKitanov yes

Comment: When using only `mapStateToProps`, one may omit the second argument to `connect`.  It's not necessary to pass `null`

Comment: For reverse case mapStateToProps without mapDispatchToProps no need to pass null. only pass mapStateToProps

Comment: Why `null` and not `undefined`? Edit: Apparently both are ok according to the manual: https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options

Comment: @LarsNyström for me, semantics of null works better here. It's like "definitely nothing"

Comment: For me it's the other way around. From the receivers point of view, `function myfunc(prop) { return prop === undefined }` would return true both for `myfunc()` and `myfunc(undefined)`. Passing undefined is like not passing anything at all. Whereas passing null is like, "I passed you something, but it's actually nothing".

Comment: @LarsNyström "Passing undefined is like not passing anything at all", that's not true. Certain libraries depend on `arguments.length` to see how many arguments you've provided, and how you meant to invoke the function.

`(function(f) { return arguments.length; })(undefined) // 1`, `(function(f) { return arguments.length; })() // 0`. Interesting blog about this subject: https://blog.sentry.io/2016/02/03/wrap-javascript-functions

Comment: `connect` should have accepted a object literal as a parameter instead of list of arguments.

Comment: @theUtherSide it should be noted that when using TypeScript passing `null` as the second argument to `connect` (in lieu of `mapDispatchToProps`) causes type checking to fail) so it is necessary to simply use `connect(mapStateToProps)`. Tested with `TS 3.9.6` and `Redux 4.0.5`